# unreal engine: совместная разработка

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Есть команда из 4х разрабов. Вопрос: как мы можем совместно работать над одним проектом, синхронизируя изменения? Ранее работали только по отдельности, по тому подобного рода опыта не имеем

Comment: Git. (Ответ получился таким коротким, что приходится писать это)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не могу оставить коммент, пишу так:
 в UE4 есть плагин Git, как сказал товарищ в комментарии, а также имеется в наличии плагин multi-User Editing, позволяющий работать одновременно над одним проектом нескольким людям. Эпики выпускали [видео](https://youtu.be/MEKACTnXLJ0) о работе с этим плагином

Answer (score 0):

Для обмена большим количеством тяжелого контента нужно:
Кастомный Git сервер, без ограничений на хранилище
Платный Git сервер
Или же SVN или Perforce сервер.
Мы используем перфорс. Эпик геймс использует перфорс для разработки, а результат уже выкладывает на гит.